# how to change repositorycombobox format

Tags: c#, winforms, repository, devexpress

I want to ask how do I change repositoryitembox format.
as you can see on my gridview display

[image]

beforehand I am already changing the column of date format on form load

```
gridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
gridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";
```

and I want to change the repository itembox format. for now when I search the format was like this

[image]

edited1 :
the code to fill the repository combobox is like this

```
  private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
  GridView view = sender as GridView;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {

            if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i) == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            string date = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"].ToString();
   if (!repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Contains(date))
            {
                repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Add(date);

            }
}
}
```

maybe i think, should change the value of string to date

Comment: Handle the ShownEditor event and there try to specify DisplayFormat or EditFormat property on the editor of current cell which you have put in the edit mode.

Comment: iam not understand

Comment: How can you format string in comboboxedit?? You can add your custom values in comboboxedit but cannot specify displayformat on comboboxedit  for datetime values.. I do not think it is possible.. let me check it is possible or not..

Comment: can you check again on the edited?
because on gridview its only change the visual or display. its not really change the date format

Comment: Could you provide a small sample that illustrate this behaviour??

Comment: iam trying to use a sample of add a variable of converting the value `string date` to `datetime` got me error